# Filter Object 's Listviews by Users in Apex

Tags: apex, list-view

We have a requirement to get all Object 's ListView of the organization in apex code and display it on the page. This is easily possible with the query on the ListView.

```
Select Id,Name,SobjectType From ListView
```

But ListViews that are private to specific users are also coming in the query. We don't want to show the ListView which is private to user.

So basically we need some kind of filter on ListView to differentiate it by User.
Can someone please suggest, if it is possible in Salesforce Apex or not? Or if there is any workaround for the same?